# jQuery remove with clone

Tags: jquery

I downloaded the jquery cookbook and tried those exercise inside of it. but I had a problem in one of it's exercises

the cloning code is working but not the .remove below, according to the cookbook, the .remove should remove the the original  element.

Please help with this guys, is that code it not working anymore? or there's a new syntax for it?

here's the code:

**Html:**

```
<ul id="a">
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
</ul>
<ul id="b"></ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    jQuery('ul#a li')
        .click(function(){alert('List Item Clicked')})
        .parent()
        .clone(true)
        .find('li')
        .appendTo('#b')
        .end()
        .end()
        .remove();
</script>
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve???

Comment: i want the .remove to be functional, i think it's not working.
it said on cookbook that .remove will remove the <li> on <ul id="a"> once it cloned on <ul id="b">

Comment: it is working as it should do so...check out my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine as intended it to do ...because of using `.end()` the remove not working for your `list` as far as the `.end()` function is concern

**If we need an older element set, we can use end() to pop the sets back off of the stack**
COURTESY BY  [JQUERY](http://api.jquery.com/end/)

you can easily understand by seeing following two Fiddles

[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg3n4/1/) is where your remove can't work

[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/Sg3n4/5/) is where your remove works

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do but it looks like maybe you want to add the item clicked from a and put it into b and then remove it from a??

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Jc6ZFVoooo4ybBCofafw?p=preview)

```
$('#a li').click(function() {
  alert('List Item Clicked')
  $(this).remove()
    .clone(true)
    .appendTo('#b');
});
```

Or perhaps you're missing another ".end()"

```
$('ul#a li')
    .click(function(){alert('List Item Clicked')})
    .parent()
    .clone(true)
    .find('li')
    .appendTo('#b')
    .end()
    .end()
    .end()
    .remove();
```

This will take all items from a, clone them, and then remove "a" altogether.

Comment: yah something like that :), thanks.

just few question, why the .remove doesn't work with clone? i tried it and it clone the <li> on <ul id="a"> but it doesn't remove the original

Comment: Look at the second part that I posted.  I think you're missing an end() to finish the appendTo statement. [Plinker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pfb1uyiHsjKiig7jsk1E?p=preview)  When you look at the DOM all items are in "b".

Answer (score 1):

try removing end() in your code and try.
here is the working code in fiddle

```
jQuery('ul#a li')
    .click(function(){alert('List Item Clicked')})
    .parent()
    .clone(true)
    .find('li')
    .appendTo('#b')
     .end()
    .remove();
```

Comment: Removing a single `end()` removes `ul#b` instead of `ul#a`. Not what is desired in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this you can add from upper list to lower and also from lower to upper
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EJ78D/1/)

HTML

```
<ul id="a">
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>list</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<ul id="b"></ul>
```

JS

```
$('body').on("click","#a li",function() {

  $(this).remove()
    .clone(true)
    .appendTo('#b');
});

$('body').on("click","#b li",function() {

  $(this).remove()
    .clone(true)
    .appendTo('#a');
});
```